# Wikimedia maps returns error 429 on internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, wikimedia, http-status-code-429

Our application uses wikimedia maps as background map. It works properly in Chrome, but in Internet Explorer wikimedia service returns error 429 with message "Our servers are currently under maintenance or experiencing a technical problem".

This situation happens only in our server. When I start application on localhost it works fine in both Chrome and Internet Explorer.

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Which version of the IE browser and What is the version of your server OS? Is it any older version then IE 11? If yes then try to upgrade to the IE 11 browser. I found that this error may occur when the server is getting too many requests. If possible then try to provide any sample example to test the issue. Try to make the settings of the IE browser similar to the IE browser which is working fine. I suggest you consult the  Wikimedia support to know their opinion on this issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT The problem happens on our development server, when I run application locally map loads properly. I used the same Internet Explorer in latest version to test both cases. Code is the same on dev server and my machine.

Comment: If possible then please provide the sample code to test the issue. The only description is not helpful to get an idea about the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our dev server was set to HTTP while localhost was set to HTTPS. This caused the issue.